# Print non-ASCII characters

Tags: python, terminal

I would like to render the special non-ASCII characters on the console, like the ones used in old DOS programs to draw windows in a terminal.  I specifically want to draw the characters they use in rendering windows/dialogs/tables, as shown here:

[image: Norton Commander DOS menus]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how to directly print to a console, although a library like `curses` is definitely easier.

Figure out what characters your console supports:

```
import sys
print('encoding =',sys.stdout.encoding)
print(bytes(range(256)).decode(sys.stdout.encoding)
```

> ```
> encoding = cp437
>  ☺☻♥♦
> ♫☼►◄↕‼¶§▬↨↑↓→←∟↔▲▼ !"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~⌂Çüéâäà
> åçêëèïîìÄÅÉæÆôöòûùÿÖÜ¢£¥₧ƒáíóúñÑªº¿⌐¬½¼¡«»░▒▓│┤╡╢╖╕╣║╗╝╜╛┐└┴┬├─┼╞╟╚╔╩╦╠═╬╧╨╤╥╙╘╒╓╫╪┘┌█▄▌▐▀αßΓπΣσµτΦΘΩδ∞φε∩≡±≥≤⌠⌡÷≈°∙·√ⁿ²
> ■
> ```

Then print them as Unicode characters.  Make sure to save the source file in UTF-8 (Python 3's default) or declare the encoding used in the source file with a `#coding: encoding` comment.  UTF-8 can handle any character, but if you print one your terminal doesn't support you'll get a `UnicodeEncodeError` in pre-3.6 Python.

```
print('╔═╦═╗╓─╥─╖╒═╤═╕┌─┬─┐')
print('║ ║ ║║ ║ ║│ │ ││ │ │')
print('╠═╬═╣╟─╫─╢╞═╪═╡├─┼─┤')
print('║ ║ ║║ ║ ║│ │ ││ │ │')
print('╚═╩═╝╙─╨─╜╘═╧═╛└─┴─┘')
```

> ```
> ╔═╦═╗╓─╥─╖╒═╤═╕┌─┬─┐
> ║ ║ ║║ ║ ║│ │ ││ │ │
> ╠═╬═╣╟─╫─╢╞═╪═╡├─┼─┤
> ║ ║ ║║ ║ ║│ │ ││ │ │
> ╚═╩═╝╙─╨─╜╘═╧═╛└─┴─┘
> ```

Answer (score 3):

You can use Python [`curses`](http://docs.python.org/library/curses.html) library, it's a part of standard library on *nix systems, or you can use [Urwid](http://excess.org/urwid/) that is a higher level library for creating console interfaces.

[Constants](http://docs.python.org/library/curses.html#constants) paragraph of the documentation contains information about how special characters can be drawn in X Emulators (if they support VT100s inherited features). If the emulator doesn't support such alternative character set - ascii approximation is used. I suppose that this is what you're looking for.

Comment: close enough. I updated my question with the specific requirement, not sure if and how curses draws those special characters.

Comment: curses allows to do that if your terminal supports (see constants section)